# Как в vue.js + typeScript, выводится тип для this у методов

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript, frontend, this

В доке vue.js для подключения typescript рекомендуют использовать конструкцию типа -

```
const Component = Vue.extend({
  // вывод типов включён
})
```

Но я не совсем понимаю, как она работает?

*Т.е. я понимаю, что берутся типы для vue.extend из файлов vue.d.ts и options.d.ts. Но я не совсем понимаю, как работает этот вывод типов*

**Т.е. я не совсем понимаю, как на TypeScript написать метод, таким образом, что бы тип параметра выводился как во vue, т.е. хочется понять как работает файл vue.d.ts выводя по параметру(конфигу) тип для this у методов, может кто нибудь может подсказать, или скинуть какой нибудь простой пример?**